# SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect breaking correct sprite movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am working on a SpriteKit app with sprites bouncing around the screen (iOS 8, iPad, landscape only, Objective-C).

As a test case I have a sprite starting at the middle of the bottom of the screen then travelling up and to the right at 45 degrees. This works fine if I do not have a edge body around the screen, but behaves very strangely when I add the edge loop (comment out the edge loop and it works again).

```
self.physicsBody= [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

NOTE: I have added an update at the end which explains the behaviour but not the cause.

---

NSLog shows the edge loop being created with the expected frame ({{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}), and the sprite being added with the correct position and velocity.

By the time `didSimulatePhysics` is called the first time through the rendering loop, the sprite's position has moved to a point a quarter of the way up the screen (in landscape) and the dx component of the velocity has become zero. The sprite then travels vertically, bouncing up and down over a distance of ~512 points centered within the screen.

In other words, the sprite seems to move up and down along a vertical line between {384, 384} and {384, 896}, as though the edge loop is positioned at {{384, 384}, {0, 512}} instead of {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}.

If I change the starting position of the sprite to be on this line, it starts at the correct position, but still loses it's x velocity component and remains constrained to this line. If I start the sprite within the y range of this line but with an x coordinate off the line, it immediately moves to the nearest point on the line and the same behaviour continues.

As suggested in other questions I have tried presenting the `SKScene` from the view controller's `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but the behaviour is the same.

I have tried hard coding the edge loop frame - no change. The behaviour is also the same on the simulator and a device.

I have another toy app with seemingly identical code for presenting the `SKScene`, setting up the edge loop and spawning sprites which works fine.

The following code is from the SKScene subclass:

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size;
{
    if (!(self= [super initWithSize:size])) return nil;
    
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate= self;
    self.physicsWorld.gravity= CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0);
    
    self.spriteAtlas= [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"sprites"];
    
    srandom((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    
    return self;
}



- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view;
{
    if (!self.contentCreated)
    {
        [self createTestSceneContent];
        self.contentCreated= YES;
    }
}



- (void)createTestSceneContent;
{
    self.backgroundColor= [SKColor whiteColor];
    self.scaleMode= SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    self.name= @"scene";
    
    CGRect fr= self.frame;
    
    NSLog(@"bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(fr));
    
    // commenting out the following line resolves the issue
    self.physicsBody= [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:fr];
    
    self.physicsBody.friction= 0.0;
    self.physicsBody.restitution= 1.0;
    self.physicsBody.linearDamping= 0.0;
    self.physicsBody.angularDamping= 0.0;
    
    SKSpriteNode *ball= [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:[self.spriteAtlas textureNamed:@"ball"]];
    
    ball.name= @"ball";
    ball.physicsBody= [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width / 2.0];
    ball.physicsBody.dynamic= YES;
    ball.physicsBody.mass= 1.0;
    ball.physicsBody.restitution= 1.0;
    ball.physicsBody.friction= 0.0;
    ball.physicsBody.linearDamping= 0.0;
    ball.physicsBody.angularDamping= 0.0;
    ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity= NO;
    ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask= 1;
    
    ball.position= CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0, ball.size.height / 2.0);
    ball.physicsBody.velocity= CGVectorMake(-75.0, 75.0);;
    
    [self addChild:ball];
    
    NSLog(@"createTestSceneContent - p= %@, v= %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(ball.position), NSStringFromCGVector(ball.physicsBody.velocity));
}



- (void)didSimulatePhysics;
{
    SKNode *ball= [self childNodeWithName:@"ball"];
    
    NSLog(@"didSimulatePhysics     - p= %@, v= %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(ball.position), NSStringFromCGVector(ball.physicsBody.velocity));
}
```

and produces the following log output:

> bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect: {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}
>
> createTestSceneContent - p= {384, 15}, v= {-75, 75}
>
> didSimulatePhysics     - p= {383.90228, 389.04977}, v= {0, 75}
>
> didSimulatePhysics     - p= {383.91571, 390.29974}, v= {0, 75}
>
> didSimulatePhysics     - p= {383.92258, 392.17471}, v= {0, 75}
>
> ...
>
> didSimulatePhysics     - p= {383.92499, 637.17346}, v= {0, 75}
>
> didSimulatePhysics     - p= {383.92499, 638.42346}, v= {0, 75}
>
> didSimulatePhysics     - p= {383.92499, 638.42346}, v= {0, -75}
>
> didSimulatePhysics     - p= {383.92499, 637.17346}, v= {0, -75}

---

UPDATE:

After a lot of experimenting with adding different edge bodies I can explain what is happening, but not why.

Any edge body I add seems to take effect 384 points from the position where the body is. 384 is half the width of the landscape iPad screen.

For example if I add an edge along the left hand side of the screen:

```
self.physicsBody= [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) toPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, self.size.height)];
```

the sprite will bounce of it at x == 384.

So with an edge loop sized for the frame, the ball gets confined into an area inset 384 points from the edges of the screen, which is a line 256 points long in the centre of the screen. Setting the edge loop with a rectangle 384 points outside each edge of the screen results in the correct behaviour (i.e. the sprite bounces at the screen edges):

```
self.physicsBody= [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectInset(self.frame, -384.0, -384.0)];
```

While this kludge fixes the immediate problem, I still want to understand why this is happening as I assume it is a symptom of an underlying problem that will show up in other places in the app as well.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Without posting any of your code it's next to impossible to help. The most common causes are incorrect shapes (ie wrong winding or self-intersecting) or trying to move physics bodies with actions or moving non-dynamic (edge-based) bodies in any way.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I have edited the question to include all the SKScene subclass code that seems to be involved. On the points you suggest: (1) the sprite is created with a simple rectangular image (loaded through a texture atlas), (2) no attempt to move the physics bodies through actions, just setting the position and velocity, (3) not moving the edge loop (or giving it a velocity).

Comment: why  ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity= NO; can you explain it

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @dragoneye. The affectedByGravity= NO is just because I was looking for it to bounce around the screen in straight lines (like looking down on a pool table). I realise that it is redundant given that I have also set the gravity vector to zero in the physicsWorld. This doesn't appear to be part of the issue as it occurs with affectedByGravity set to YES, NO or left as default.

Comment: just making a guess why bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect have a restitution when you already given a restitution force to the ball may be two restitution force genrateing negative velocity at some point just try to set bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect restitution to 0

Comment: @dragoneye Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried various combinations of restitution values and this does not seem to be the problem.